# Is possible to retrieve all records on a single query?

Tags: rest-api, api, query, rest

I am using this library ([forrest](https://github.com/omniphx/forrest)) to make queries in the salesforce REST API, when I do the query, it seems that salesforce returns me a pagination, I have verified it with postman as well.

for example in my app:

```
array:4 [▼
  "totalSize" => 5246
  "done" => false
  "nextRecordsUrl" => "/services/data/v53.0/query/01g1m000008dsyfAAA-500"
  "records" => array:500 [▶]
]
```

to be able to go to the next page, I have to do a new query to "nextRecordsUrl" so that it returns another 500 results, and I have to do the same until I complete all the data

Is it possible to retrieve all the data in a single query?
Is it possible to set that in the Salesforce account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected and is documented in the library you linked.

> If you are querying more than 2000 records, your response will
> include:
>
> `( [nextRecordsUrl] => /services/data/v20.0/query/01gD0000002HU6KIAW-2000 )`
>
> Simply, call `Forrest::next($nextRecordsUrl)` to return the next 2000 records.

Likewise, you can also look at the Salesforce REST API documentation for [query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_query.htm) to see a similar mention with the important distinction of *up to 2,000 records*. As Derek mentions in the comment, this can be lower based on what you're querying (object, data, etc) but isn't in your control to change. In the end, as the library mentions, you'll be relying on `nextRecordsUrl` for subsequent calls if it's needed/returned.

> When a SOQL query is executed, up to 2,000 records can be returned at
> a time in a synchronous request. If the number of results exceeds this
> limit, the response contains only the first set of results and a query
> identifier, contained in the response’snextRecordsUrl field. The
> identifier can be used in another request to retrieve the next batch
> of records.

Comment: the library mentions that the following 2000 can be consulted, it refers to pagination, it is the same thing that I am already doing but it only gives me 500 results, I did not find a way to retrieve more

Comment: @AndréCuellarAvaroma The SFDC documentation says _up to 2000_. The number you get is determined by Salesforce using some process they haven't documented or otherwise made public knowledge. We (as users) cannot change that. I imagine the number gets reduced in some relation to the amount of data contained in each row you query.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to fetch all records in one go, regardless of the api you chose. All of them have hard max limits, as well as the platform itself. Take for example, performing SOQL queries, even they have limits as per the number of records you can fetch. Generally speaking, most if not all platforms impose limits on the amount of records you can fetch and force you to paginate results.